# Errors on 1.9.2.2

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend-error

We recently migrate our server after uploading all files we getting an error messages like as shown below screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable pdo_mysql .
If you can access the php.ini then add this to php.ini

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=sqlite.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

There may be an option in cpanel to enable php extensions, i don't remember exactly where that option is so you may search it there also and enable it.

Comment: Hi, It's working but when I use that I'm getting another like as shown in [Screenshot](http://prntscr.com/edjit0).

Comment: Again if you can access your php.ini then go there and you will see something like execution limit or max execution time and memory limit . Increase both of them. Or contact your server support to increase the allowed memory limit